# Which characters can be used as regular expression delimiters?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

Which characters can be used as delimiters for a Perl regular expression? `m/re/`, `m(re)` and `måreå` all seem to work, but I'd like to know all possibilities.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> With the m you can use any pair of non-whitespace characters as delimiters.

So anything goes, except whitespace. The full paragraph for this is:

> If "/" is the delimiter then the initial m is optional. With the m you can use any pair of non-whitespace characters as delimiters. This is particularly useful for matching path names that contain "/", to avoid LTS (leaning toothpick syndrome). If "?" is the delimiter, then the match-only-once rule of ?PATTERN? applies. If "'" is the delimiter, no interpolation is performed on the PATTERN. When using a character valid in an identifier, whitespace is required after the m.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking in perlre.

Comment: That's because they aren't regex delimiters, they are operator delimiters. The regexes are what happens inside the delimiters.

Comment: Theory and practice conflict a bit here.

Comment: There are four special character that you use in pairs: ()  []  {}  <>.  Example: perl -nlE'if(m<foo>){say"FOO"}'

Comment: @shawnhcorey Is that non-regex specific but rather perl specific? I couldn't understand from documentation. Thanks.

Comment: @TOOTSKI, I don't know. I use Perl almost exclusively.

Comment: Note that you use an `s`, not an `m`, when doing a replace (aka substitute) with regular expressions. http://www.perlfect.com/articles/regex.shtml

Comment: The line from perlop actually says "With the m you can use any pair of non-whitespace (ASCII) characters as delimiters." (as of v5.36). There are many non-ASCII characters that you can use, but there are some exceptions for some paired characters.

Answer (score 7):

As is often the case, I wonder "can I write a Perl program to answer that question?".

Here is a pretty good first approximation of trying all of the printable ASCII chars:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

$_ = 'foo bar'; # something to match against

foreach my $ascii (32 .. 126) {
    my $delim = chr $ascii;
    next if $delim eq '?'; # avoid fatal error

    foreach my $m ('m', 'm ') {  # with and without space after "m"
        my $code = $m . $delim . '(\w+)' . $delim . ';';
#        print "$code\n";
        my $match;
        {
            no warnings 'syntax';
            ($match) = eval $code;
        }
        print "[$delim] didn't compile with $m$delim$delim\n" if $@;
        if (defined $match and $match ne 'foo') {
            print "[$delim] didn't match correctly ($match)\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat solution, but it's going to take a while to go through all unicode characters.

Comment: Don't worry @Tim Nordenfur, I'm sure he doesn't have to pay the computer overtime :)

Comment: Heh, I went to look through everything from 0 to 0x10ffff. About 75% of the characters don't compile as delimiters even with spaces. Most of that is above 0xFFFF though, so that weights that number considerably.

Answer (score 6):

There is currently a bug in the lexer that sometimes prevents UTF-8 characters from being used as a delimiter, even though you can sneak Latin1 by it if you aren't in full Unicode mode.

Comment: any specific chars? `use utf8; ...; $str =~ m ê ê;` works as expected here within an UTF-8 encoded script.

Comment: @Mat, note that that's a latin-1 character.

Comment: `$str =~ m ش ش` parses (and works) too, and that's not latin1 (arabic iso-8859-6).

Comment: @Mat, I don’t have time to show you the example bugs right now, but they do exist.  I bumped into them again a couple of day ago, but I have to run right now.

Answer (score 5):

Just about any non-whitespace character can be used, though identifier characters have to be separated from the initial m by whitespace.  Though when you use a single quote as the delimiter, it disables interpolation and most backslash escaping.