# date conversion in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am using perl to access a DB from where I am getting the date in DD-MON-YYYY format. I need to perform 2 operations:

1. Convert this format to a MM/DD/YYYY format.
2. Compare this date with two dates to see if it lies in that time range.

   my $chdate = '15-Feb-2013';

   sub get_stats
   {

   ```
   my %map = ( 'Jan' => '01', 'Feb' => '02', 'Mar' => '03', 'Apr' => '04',
               'May' => '05', 'Jun' => '06', 'Jul' => '07', 'Aug' => '08',
               'Sep' => '09', 'Oct' => '10', 'Nov' => '11', 'Dec' => '12');

       $chdate =~ s/(..)-(...)-(....)/$map{$2}\/$1\/$3/;
       print "New date: $chdate";
   ```

   }

How do I perform the (2) operation?

I have an old version of Perl (no Time::Piece module), which I do not have privileges to update :)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Show us relevant code so community can help you to overcome problems.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/TimeDate-2.30/lib/Date/Format.pm

Comment: @aditya [DateTime! Only Hardcode! :)](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime)

Comment: @defaultlocale sometimes i think, that not relevant piece of code, but even 'google try' could be good enough..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For (2) you can do this:

```
sub dateAsNumber # Arg mm/dd/yyyy - Converts to a number to be compared
{
   $_[0]=~m%(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d\d\d)%;
   return (($3 * 400 + $1) * 40 + $2);
}

$test = &dateAsNumber($testDateAsString);

if (&dateAsNumber($startDateAsString) < $test &&
    &dateAsNumber($endDateAsString) > $test)
{
   print "$test date is between $startDateAsString and $endDateAsString\n";
}
else
{
   print "$test date is NOT between $startDateAsString and $endDateAsString\n";
}
```

Comment: how did you determine (($3 * 400 + $1) * 40 + $2) formula?

Comment: You just need to compare two numbers - There are no more than 400 days in the year or 40 days in the month (I rounded up). Does not matter if there are gaps in the number line.

Comment: Thanks Ed. Just a comment, shouldn't the regex be modified as:     $_[0] =~ /(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d\d\d\d)/;

Comment: @aditya iIn Perl (if memory serves me right) you can use anything for the pattern delimiter. Corrected it though - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770590/which-characters-can-be-used-as-regular-expression-delimiters

Comment: Wouldn't `$3 . $1 . $2` work just as well as your overcomplicated formula?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use the [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) module. It has been a core module since Perl5 v9.5 and so probably won't need installing.

Just decode the date using `strptime` and reencode it using `strftime`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $date = '28-jul-1986';

print Time::Piece->strptime($date, '%d-%b-%Y')->strftime('%m/%d/%Y');
```

**output**

```
07/28/1986
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am using perl-5.8.6, and it complains about Time::Piece module.

Comment: You *really* should update your version of Perl. v8.6 is over eight years old and there have been four major releases since then. Are you able to install `Time::Piece` from CPAN? I see no reason why it shouldn't work on your system.

Comment: I am using perl from a server, don't have the privileges to update the version. I found a novice way to make the conversion :)

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your dates to [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) object then you can compare them using the standard numeric comparison operators. So you could do something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $start_date_str = '1-mar-2013';
my $end_date_str   = '31-mar-2013';
my $date_to_test_str = '4-mar-2013';

my $in_fmt  = '%d-%b-%Y';
my $out_fmt = '%m/%d/%y'; # Warning: Illogical format!

my $start_date_tp = Time::Piece->strptime(
  $start_date_str, $in_fmt
);
my $end_date_tp = Time::Piece->strptime(
  $end_date_str, $in_fmt
);
my $date_to_test_tp = Time::Piece->strptime(
  $date_to_test_str, $in_fmt
);

print $date_to_test_tp->strftime($out_fmt), ' is ';
unless ($start_date_tp <= $date_to_test_tp and
    $date_to_test_tp <= $end_date_tp) {
      print ' not ';
}
say 'between the two test dates';
```