# Perl program for text work

Tags: perl

I am writing a script in Perl, but Im just a beginner. This program downloads html page and tries to find phrases bounded by tags. I attached a code below, when I check it, there's no errors but it does nothing (no print out). So please can anybody give me some advice what can be wrong?

```
open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my $s = get("xxx.html");

foreach my $line (split(/\n/,$s)) {

  if (m,<>(.*?)<>,g) {

    if(eof()) {
        close(FILE);    }

     print "$1\n";
     last if eof();
        }    
}
```

Comment: Paired tags are actually quite tricky to get correct regular expressions for. Your regex `m,<>(.*?)<>,g` will only find content between tags looking *exactly* like this: `<>` - there probably are none in the HTML.

Comment: I hve between tags letter "b" so it is specific defined, problem isn't in this ....

Answer (score 3):

I do spot numerous problems.

1. `if (//g)` makes no sense and can cause actual (subtle) problems. Remove the `g`.
2. You check `eof()` (twice!) without ever using `<>`.  huh?
3. You close file handle `FILE`, yet you never opened any such file handle.
4. You close file handle `FILE` after checking if a different file handle has reached eof.
5. You say your code doesn't do anything, yet you didn't bother to check if `get` returned something other than undef.

By the way, always use `use strict; use warnings;`. Not sure if you did or not.

Comment: 1. when I remove "g" - appear warning "Search pattern not terminated"
... 2. now I have eof() in "# comment" and nothing changed ... 3. and "use strict" I have

Comment: 1. You removed more than `g` if you get that error and you didn't before.   2. That doesn't mean it made any sense whatever to have it. 3. Well, that's only half of the recommendation.

Comment: 1. I remove only ",g" nothing more .... 2. I know that eof() doesnt make any sence because I use only variables but I donw know how to rewrite now.... 3. now I write "use warnings" and it print out some weird warning :/

Comment: @LuBoB Removing the comma `,` before the `g` was one of the problems. In Perl the `m` operator is followed by a character that marks the beginning of the pattern, the same character marks the end of the pattern. So in `m,abc,g` the start and end of the pattern is marked by the `,` characters. More commonly `/` is used as in `m/abc/` and in that case the `m` can also be omitted. Perl also allows the bracketing characters ie ** () [] {} <> ** to be used in pairs, eg `m(abc)`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770590/which-characters-can-be-used-as-regular-expression-delimiters

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XML module(XML::Parser) available over [here](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/XML-Parser-2.41/Parser.pm)
It grabs the text between the tags.

Comment: could you help with syntax with XML - what would be changed in code ?? ... I dont have much time a becasue Im new in Perl it could take a lot of time...

Comment: There is an example in the link which I had specified ,its not much difficult to understand.