# how to use grep with an array in perl?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I have the following lines of code in a perl file:

```
@arr1 = grep(/"$subslots_det[0]"/,@grepped_int);
```

for ur reference the @grepped_int array's dump looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = [
'GigabitEthernet4/2/1   unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    ',
'GigabitEthernet7/1     unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    ',
'GigabitEthernet7/2     unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    ',
        ]
```

Here lets assume,
    $subslots_det[0] = "4/2";

So the grep statement should match:

```
GigabitEthernet4/2/1   unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    ',
```

Right now it doesnt not do that,iam suspecting it is because of the forward slash in 4/2.
Is there a way i can escape the forward slash in the following command:

```
@arr1 = grep(/"$subslots_det[0]"/,@grepped_int);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of double quotes.

```
@arr1 = grep(/$subslots_det[0]/, @grepped_int);
```

Regular expression [itself serves as quoting](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators), and therefore the quotes around `$subslots_det[0]` simply serve as literal quote characters, so you're trying to match `"4/2"` instead of `4/2` .

Ex:

```
>perl -e '@s=("a/1","b/2"); @res=grep(/$s[0]/,("aa/1","bb/2")); print @res."\n"'
1

>perl -e '@s=("a/1","b/2"); @res=grep(/"$s[0]"/,("aa/1","bb/2")); print @res."\n"'
0
```

Also, if you worry about escaping "/" character (which you should not unless it's used as a literal inside the regex itself), you can always [change the regex delimiter](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) from "/" to "#" or [any other character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770590/which-characters-can-be-used-as-regular-expression-delimiters):

```
@arr1 = grep(m#$subslots_det[0]#, @grepped_int);
@arr1 = grep(m!$subslots_det[0]!, @grepped_int);
```

Comment: I tried it without the quote,still doesnt match, but if i do @arr1 = grep(/4\/2/,@grepped_int);

Comment: @user3094070 - the escaping of the "/" is ONLY needed when it's a literal character. You can easily test that by changing regex character from "/" to "#" so you don't need to care about escaping it: `@arr1 = grep(m#$s[0]#,@grepped_int)`

Comment: sorry my mistake:) i had defined the criteria for match differently,thats y it dint match,now it works perfectly,thanks a lot,answer accepted.