# Is there a difference betwen qq(<text>) and "<text>" in Perl?

Tags: perl

In perl you can use both `qq(<text>)` and `"<text>"` to create double quoted text. Is there any difference between the two?

(Same question for `q(<text>)` and `'<text>'`)

Comment: No, but let me point out a difference in usage, just in case: with the operator form we can then use double quotes inside, `qq("quoted")`, while with quotes we have to escape them.

Answer (score 4):

No.

`"<text>"` is short for `qq"<text>"`.

`'<text>'` is short for `q'<text>'`.

[Quote-Like Operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-Like-Operators)

Comment: With q and qq you can use any character as delimiter that you dont't need inside the text, so you don't have to escape anything.

Comment: Tad went to look at which characters can be used as delimiters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5770976/2766176 When I expanded his script to handle everything from 0 to 0x10ffff, only about 25% can be used (but you expected that once you cross 0xFFFF). Also, there are various Unicode paired delimiters that are deprecated, such as 《. You can't use those without enabling a feature.

Answer (score 3):

Deparse Perl programs to see how Perl interpreted you wrote. When you use the generalized quotes, you get back the single and double quotes:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e '$s = q(abc)'
$s = 'abc';
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Deparse -e '$s = qq/ab "c" d/'
$s = 'ab "c" d';
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Deparse -e '$s = qq(abc$$)'
$s = "abc${$}";
-e syntax OK
```

Besides using these to allow the ' and " to appear in the string, I find them very handy for one liners so that the `'` and `"` don't trigger shell problems:

```
% perl -le "print qq(PID is $$)"
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to them being identical, there is the point that you can use `q()` `qq()` with different delimiters (like you can with many Perl operators) to make quoting simpler. For example `qq#The movie "Foo"#`, `q{Some other 'Foo'}`. Compare

```
"Bob said, \"What's that?\""      'Bob said, "What\'s that?"'   qq(Bob said, "What's that?")
"Kim whispers, \"(...)\""         qq|Kim whispers, "(...)"|
s/http:\/\/www.example.com\//http:\/\/www.example.net\//  # "leaning toothpick syndrome" (1)
s#http://www.example.com/#http://www.example.net/#        # fixed
```

(1): [leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)